# SSAS cell permission

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence

I'm trying to restrict the access to the cube to certain dimension members. I Used the following function on the "Cell Data" tab of the role editor:

```
[Magatzems].[Codi Magatzem].CURRENTMEMBER = [Magatzems].[Codi Magatzem].&[27] or [Magatzems].[Codi Magatzem].CURRENTMEMBER = [Magatzems].[Codi Magatzem].&[57]
```

and it works ok on the members, but I don't get my totals calculated.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing it the wrong way. It's not in the "Cell Data" tab, It's in the "Dimension Data" tab. The "Enable Visual Totals" checkbox has to be checked.